# how to have a QVector of QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qmap, qvector

I wanna have a QVector of QMap. I used this syntax:

```
QVector<QMap<QString, QString>> x;
x[0].insert("name", "jim");
x[0].insert("lname", "helpert");
x[1].insert("name", "dwight");
x[1].insert("lname", "schrute");
```

but this is not working:

[image]

I'd appreciate it if someone guide me to the correct format.

Comment: What is `d`?  I see a variable named `x`.  Also, please be more specific, as to "this is not working" means.  Doesn't compile?  Doesn't run correctly?

Comment: I corrected the variable name:) also added the image. hope that's clear.

Comment: What functions are used to add items to a `QVector`?  Are you calling any of those functions to add an entry to the vector?  I am not a user of `QVector`, but if it's anything like `std::vector`, you don't add items by using `[ ]`.

Comment: that's right. my bad. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Index Out of Range" error comes up because you are trying to access an element of the vector which doesn't exist. Instead of accessing a particular index/element of the array it would be better to create a QMap outside of the QVector first and then `x.push_back(map)` so the map will be happily placed at the back of the QVector.

A similar thing applies to normal C++ with `std::vector` as you need to either `push_back` or `emplace_back` data onto the vector

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "Index Out Of Range" because you are accessing an empty QVector. You need to first insert QMap elements to QVector. Then you can access x[0] -> for first QMap at 0th index, x[1] -> for second QMap at 1st index.......
Make QMap object. Insert Elments to it.
Make QVector object. Insert that QMap object to this QVector.
Read the documents and use appropriate functions for it https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/